# How to import an excel file that contains line breaks with-in the cell text

Tags: ios, excel, parsing

I have an excel file with some data (with multiple columns and multiple rows). I want to import this data into my core-data based database. I'm struggling to import the data, because the text in the cells contain line breaks.

I've tried the following:

1.) Export excel to Tab-delimited text file

2.) Write an import route in iOS that reads the tab-delimited text file using the following code:

```
NSCharacterSet *tabCharacterSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"\t"];

NSArray *rows = [dataString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
NSArray *columns = [row componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:tabCharacterSet];
```

**Problem:** I have 1000 `rows` with 15 `columns` each. The parsing routine returns more than 1000 `rows` and less than 15 `columns`. The line breaks with-in the cell are not being handled properly by the parsing routine.

I get the same results if I use

`[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"\r\n"];`

or

`[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"\r"];`

instead of

`[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]`

but it completely fails if I use

`[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"\n"];`

**How can I parse the excel-data properly?**

**Perhaps I can use Regex expressions to get line components? Any idea/pointers?**

**UPDATE (Sample XLSX and Export File):**

[image: Sample XLSX File]
[image: Sample TAB Delimited Text File]

Comment: Can you show an example of what the TSV file looks like with line breaks **inside** a row?

Comment: CSV/TSV values that have line breaks in the value will be in quotes. Values that contain the field separator will also be in quotes. You can't properly parse CSV/TSV files by splitting the text by a simple separator. You need to deal with quoted values. Parsing a CSV/TSV file properly is much more involved that most people think.

Comment: Edited, to include the sample XLSX and export file screen-shots.

Comment: I would recommend if possible to use an excel macro that connects to your DB via ADODB, the performance likely won't be great, but it should properly wrap the in cell line breaks so that it uploads correctly into the db.

Comment: You can also read the values directly from the xls file using an open source ObjectiveC framework: https://github.com/dhoerl/DHlibxls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me involves using `NSScanner` class.

```
- (NSArray *)parseCSVFileString {
    NSMutableArray *rows = [NSMutableArray array];

    // Get newline character set
    NSMutableCharacterSet *newlineCharacterSet = (id)[NSMutableCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet];
    [newlineCharacterSet formIntersectionWithCharacterSet:[[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet] invertedSet]];

    // Characters that are important to the parser
    NSMutableCharacterSet *importantCharactersSet = (id)[NSMutableCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@",\""];
    [importantCharactersSet formUnionWithCharacterSet:newlineCharacterSet];

    // Create scanner, and scan string
    NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:self];
    [scanner setCharactersToBeSkipped:nil];

    while (![scanner isAtEnd]) {

        @autoreleasepool {
            BOOL insideQuotes = NO;
            BOOL finishedRow = NO;
            NSMutableArray *columns = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];
            NSMutableString *currentColumn = [NSMutableString string];
            while ( !finishedRow ) {
                NSString *tempString;

                if ([scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:importantCharactersSet intoString:&tempString]) {
                    [currentColumn appendString:tempString];
                }

                if ([scanner isAtEnd]) {

                    if (![currentColumn isEqualToString:@""]) [columns addObject:currentColumn];

                    finishedRow = YES;

                } else if ([scanner scanCharactersFromSet:newlineCharacterSet intoString:&tempString]) {

                    if (insideQuotes) {
                        // Add line break to column text
                        [currentColumn appendString:tempString];

                    } else {
                        // End of row
                        if (![currentColumn isEqualToString:@""]) [columns addObject:currentColumn];

                        finishedRow = YES;
                    }

                } else if ([scanner scanString:@"\"" intoString:NULL]) {

                    if (insideQuotes && [scanner scanString:@"\"" intoString:NULL]) {
                        // Replace double quotes with a single quote in the column string.
                        [currentColumn appendString:@"\""];

                    } else {
                        // Start or end of a quoted string.
                        insideQuotes = !insideQuotes;
                    }

                } else if ([scanner scanString:@"," intoString:NULL]) {

                    if (insideQuotes) {
                        [currentColumn appendString:@","];

                    } else {
                        // This is a column separating comma
                        [columns addObject:currentColumn];
                        currentColumn = [NSMutableString string];
                        [scanner scanCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet] intoString:NULL];
                    }
                }
            }

            if ( [columns count] > 0 ) [rows addObject:columns];
        }
    }

    return rows;
}
```

Reference: http://www.macresearch.org/cocoa-scientists-part-xxvi-parsing-csv-data